# how to model nested random effect in nlme package

Tags: r

I have two factors in the linear mixed model. Factor A is treated as fixed effect, factor B is treated as random effect and nested into factor A. Can anyone tell me how to do this using nlme R package?

I know that `lme( response~ factorA, random=~1|factorA/factorB)` is one way to model. however, this function treat factor A as random effect.

Comment: Why wouldn't this just be: `lme( response~ factorA, random=~1|factorB)`?

Comment: factor B is nested within factor A.

Comment: Right, but how is that different than specifying factor A as random?

Comment: no one has specified any factor to be random. Only the intercept is being specified as random across some factor. DWin's first suggestion seems reasonable if you want the intercept to be random across levels of `factorB`

Comment: Perhaps you need to describe, in English, your study a bit more clearly so it's not a guessing game.

Answer (score 4):

It seems you have data structured such that observations of individuals are nested within groups that are identified by `factorB`. These groups are further nested within larger groupings identified by `factorA`. You do not want the highest level of this hierarchy to have it's own random intercept term. Instead you just model variation with the factor included as a fixed effect. Fine. Then what is left is to allow the intercept to vary across `factorB`. This is precisely what **DWin** suggested.

```
lme(response ~ factorA, random=~1|factorB)
```

It's not entirely clear that this is really what you *want*, however. It's also not clear what the real structure of your data is from the question you've written. If you update the question, I will update this answer to suit.

Answer (score 4):

This depends on how your variables are coded.  You might have distinct names for the variables in `factorB`, like this; then just having `factorB` as a random effect, is sufficient.

```
factorA  factorB
bob      bob1
bob      bob2
bob      bob3
jane     jane1
jane     jane2
jane     jane3

lme(response ~ factorA, random=~1|factorB)
```

But you might have the same coding for the variables in `factorB` for each level of `factorA`, like this; then just having `factorB` as a random effect is not correct; you instead need the random effect to be the interaction between them, I think code using `:` would work, but it might be more readable to make a new variable.

```
factorA  factorB
bob      rep1
bob      rep2
bob      rep3
jane     rep1
jane     rep2
jane     rep3

lme(response ~ factorA, random=~1|factorA:factorB)

dat$factorAB <- with(dat, factor(paste(factorA, factorB), sep="."))
lme(response ~ factorA, random=~1|factorAB)
```

Comment: I think `dat$factorAB <- with(dat, factor(paste(factorA, factorB), sep="."))` is the same as `factorA:factorB` aside from the character that will separate the combinations.

Comment: Also, if `factorB` uniquely identifies each data point (which I recognize we do not know), then allowing a parameter to vary across that factor is duplicating the residual error term (i.e. probably not allowed).

Comment: About @ndoogan's first comment: Yes, `:` and `paste` do have very similar results, though `:` will make levels for every combination of the two, even if that combination doesn't exist.  I think using `:` in the formula works, but one should check that any extra levels don't cause a problem, plus make sure that the formula mechanism handles `:` appropriately.

Comment: @ndoogan's second comment is right on: my example data set should include multiple rows for each combination, otherwise the random effect is unneeded and depending on the software, will fail.

Comment: Glad to hear it, @Colin.  Please check the check mark by the answer so that others know it answered it.  You can also up-vote any answer (including this one) that was helpful).  Welcome to StackOverflow!